# How to pass multiple commands into salt cmd.run?

Tags: salt-stack

I need to execute a script with a properties file which on the server requires me to be in the directory of the script and the properties file. How can I get salt to achieve this without having salt execute another script that takes care of the directory change?

i have tried

```
salt 'minion_id' cmd.run 'cd /my/directory && sh my_script.sh my_file.properties'
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the generic case, `&&` should work fine, as long as each command in the chain exits with 0. If they won't (and that's okay), you can use `;` rather than `&&`. You may also need to fully qualify the path to any binaries (such as /bin/sh rather than just sh), as the cmd.run env tends to have a rather bare path.

That said, the cmd.run module supports a `cwd` parameter (see [the documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cmdmod.html#salt.modules.cmdmod.run)) which specifies the directory to execute in:

Try something like:

```
salt 'minion_id' cmd.run '/bin/sh my_script.sh my_file.properties' cwd=/my/directory
```

Or if your script is executable and has a shebang:

```
salt 'minion_id' cmd.run './my_script.sh my_file.properties' cwd=/my/directory
```